# POP3 has stopped working in Outlook 2013 for one of three .pst files

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

clarification:
The Outlook 2013 profile has 3 .pst files.
-- one is for a domain that is hosting by 1&1 (no issues)
-- two are for a domain that i host using hMailserver
-- one of the 2 has no issues
-- the other has the issues described below.
-- my best guess is that the issue is client side

```
  724,288,512 <== fails  .pst  hMailserver fails    
      779,264 <== works  .pst  hMailserver    
3,809,805,312 <== works  .pst  1&1
```

server:  hMailserver
leave mail on server is used
host/client:
XP/Outlook Express -- no issues
7/Outlook 2007 -- no issues

8.1/Outlook 2013 -- previously, no issues
 - has failed since 2015-05-02 11:34 Eastern Time
 - SMTP test from Outlook 2013 passes (a)
 - POP3 test from Outlook 2013 fails (b)
 - pull POP3 form Outlook 2013 fails (c)
 - send SMTP from Outlook 2013 succeeds

(a) test messages received on XP/Outlook Express and 7/Outlook 2010

(b) the POP3 test does not attempt to received e-mails.

(c)

Client side:
    outlook 2013 Receiving' reported error 0x800CCC90
    Your incoming (POP3) e-mail server has reported an internal error.

Server side:  **"SENT: -ERR Invalid command in current state."**
    "2015-05-12 21:57:09.848" "Creating session 35413"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:09.848" "SENT: +OK gerry lowry says welcome POP3"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.082" "RECEIVED: CAPA"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.082" "SENT: +OK CAPA list follows[nl]USER[nl]UIDL[nl]TOP[nl]."
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.113" "RECEIVED: USER gerry.lowry@ ..."
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.113" "SENT: +OK Send your password"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.160" "RECEIVED: PASS ***"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.300" "SENT: +OK Mailbox locked and ready"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.300" "RECEIVED: "
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.300" "SENT: -ERR Invalid command in current state."
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.331" "RECEIVED: STAT"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.347" "SENT: +OK 1110 26852027"
    "2015-05-12 21:57:10.363" "Ending session 35413"

any ideas????

**update**
restarting Outlook 2013 many times did not help; restarting Win 8.1 also does not help; occasionally more messages get downloaded.  Currently, i have messages up to 2015-05-14 15:30 Eastern Time.

**update #2**
it's as if Outlook 2013 is working to rule for this account ... i now have messages up to 2015-05-23 13:20 -- FWIW, the problem could also be server side.

**update #3**  i now have messages up to 2015-05-30 01:35